# How can create a dictionary in android?

Tags: java, android

Am developing A Malayalam-> English dictionary app in android .how can i do this
    stuff? can anyone please help me.which is the best method to create a dictionary?..all 
   answers are highly appreciative..

Answer (score 4):

A `Map` implementation seems the obvious choice for a dictionary, where the key is the Malayalm word and the value is the English word.

Comment: @user1498512, incase you are unfamiliar with `Map` the interface and implementations are in package `java.util`.

Comment: what will be the maximum size of a hash map? english words will come around 200000.Can i proceed with same technique? thank you for your reply.

Comment: @user1498512, I am unaware of any restriction on the size of `HashMap`. It is recommended that you provide an initial capacity if the map is large (see javadoc for `HashMap`).

Answer (score 1):

you can either use hashmap or dictionary class. which use key/value pair concept.
to read more about that click the link below-

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html)

Comment: Actually the `dictionary` is outdated: "Note: Do not use this class since it is obsolete. Please use the Map interface for new implementations."

Answer (score 0):

Will your database fit in the limited memory of the device?  If so, then go with some sort of Map as suggested above.

Otherwise, it gets complicated.  I would put your dictionary into an sqlite3 database and access the database from your app.  For performance improvement, I would cache each word locally in a HashMap once it's been looked up.  You can get clever and use WeakHashMap instead, which will purge entries from the cache as memory gets tight.  (Caveat: does Android implement WeakHashMap?)

Finally, consider implementing a content provider backed up by the above-mentioned sqlite3 database.  Then your dictionary is easily accessible by multiple clients and the database only needs to be opened once, by the content provider.